# Which condition is technically more efficient, i >= 0 or i > -1?

Tags: performance, comparison, cpu-usage, conditional-statements

This kind of usage is common while writing loops.

I was wondering if `i >=0` will need more CPU cycles as it has two conditions `greater than OR equal to` when compared to `i > -1`. Is one known to be better than the other, and if so, why?

Comment: I suggest you'll never notice the difference, so do what is more readable.

Comment: @SaadAbdullah why do you think so?

Comment: as it will not use conversion of positive 1 number into -1 number

Comment: from a code readability perspective, I'd always go with i >= 0

Comment: Tell you what - pick the form that you understand the best at 6:30AM after a 17 hour coding fest.

Comment: Run a timer for both loop types, and calculate which one is faster, if either one. I doubt there will be much a difference.

Comment: The fact that you read `>=` in English with a conjunctive has no bearing how much work it is for the processor.  How do you know `>` doesn't read to the computer as "greater than or equal but not equal"?

Comment: @SaadAbdullah conversion of positive number to negative? thinking too much. Java handles this internally. Performance should be the same in both form.

Comment: @mike-w won't notice the difference, because there is in fact no difference.

Comment: Is this really a 4 upvote question?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : yup, the question was funny,

Comment: @RUJordan: FTFY, now it's a four-upvote question :)

Comment: The question might be funny, but tell me about the optimization of code. :)

Comment: @JamesJithin, don't think too much. Beware to fall into over-optimization trap.

Comment: @RUJordan Oh, it's a 5-upvote question now!

Comment: nobody care about the answer yet :/

Comment: @SaadAbdullah - If nobody did, there wouldn't have been *7 upvotes* for the answer! :)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, for me optimization is optimization. Trying to make code execute faster. Will you consider writing i >= 0 or i > -1 or i > 0 || i == 0? Some thing will be faster among these.

Comment: You should focus on more important optimization, such as reduce looping, object coupling, etc.

Comment: If you think all optimization is equal, you're incredibly naive. Have you considered the effect of different JREs, operating systems and other issues that might affect this particular micro-optimization problem? Or do you imagine that you can just write "the fastest code possible"?

Comment: @Kayaman, never mentioned "fastest" anywhere. :D

Comment: @JamesJithin You were talking about CPU cycles, and in a later comment you say "for me optimization is optimization. Trying to make code execute faster". So are you stupid or just forgetful?

Comment: @Kayaman you have proved who is stupid by saying faster is same as fastest :P

Comment: Oh, I see you went into semantics. At least it means you realized that your question is completely worthless.

Comment: @Kayaman, it is my question. Good to see some answer and comments which are fruitful rather than insults and thanks for your time.

Comment: This question is not opinion-based. @SaadAbdullah is right. Comparsions with 0 are generally preferable from performance perspective, because they often save one x86 instruction compared with non-zero comparsions, because `ZF`, `CF`, etc flags are set after each arithmetic or load instruction.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor see the previous comment.

Comment: @leventov You'd need to see the actual JIT generated code to see what's happening. You can't make a direct leap from Java code to machine instructions like that.

Comment: @Kayaman my comment reason why zero-comparsions are *generally* preferable, regardless the language and compiler intelligence.

Comment: @leventov Yes, I remember this being an issue 20 years ago, it being mentioned in an X86 Assembler handbook. Now it's just a micro-optimization that potentially and probably has no effect whatsoever. It also tells that the developer is concentrating on completely trivial issues, and that he certainly won't be very productive if he's wasting time on things like comparison efficiency.

Comment: @Kayaman it still has effect of 0.5-1 CPU tics. What is more meaningful, topic starter is choosing the way of writing reverse loops for the rest of his programming career. He won't waste time on this anymore, just will use the slightly better way.

Comment: @leventov You're seriously suggesting writing reverse loops to speed up things? Haha, what next, using XOR to zero out variables? I think you people should spend a bit more time learning Java and a little less time trying to bring optimizations from other languages into it.

Comment: @Kayaman 1) I didn't suggest to rewrite existing loops. When someone really need reverse loop, he would better write `i >= 0`, that's it. 2) I know that hotspot will probably optimize comparsion with -1 to the optimal version. Repeatedly I should note that I'm explaining language-agnostic things.

Comment: @leventov Good, we seem to agree, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not correct. The JIT will implement both tests as a single machine language instruction.

And the number of CPU clock cycles is not determined by the number of comparisons to zero or -1, because the CPU should do one comparison and set flags to indicate whether the result of the comparison is <, > or =.

It's possible that one of those instructions will be more efficient on certain processors, but this kind of micro-optimization is almost always not worth doing. (It's also possible that the JIT - or javac - will actually generate *the same instructions* for both tests.)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You mean Oracle javac? (Eclipse has its own Java compiler, as does GCC.) Which version? Have you tested it?

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, comparsions (including non-strict) with zero takes one CPU instruction less. x86 architecture supports conditional jumps after any arithmetic or loading operation. It is reflected in Java bytecode instruction set, there is a group of instructions to compare the value on the top of the stack and jump: `ifeq`/`ifgt`/`ifge`/`iflt`/`ifle`/`ifne`. (See [the full list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)). Comparsion with `-1` requires additional `iconst_m1` operation (loading `-1` constant onto the stack).

The are two loops with different comparsions:

```
@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public int loopZeroCond() {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 1000; i >= 0; i--) {
        s += i;
    }
    return s;
}

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public int loopM1Cond() {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 1000; i > -1; i--) {
        s += i;
    }
    return s;
}
```

The second version is one byte longer:

```
public int loopZeroCond();
  Code:
     0: iconst_0      
     1: istore_1      
     2: sipush        1000
     5: istore_2      
     6: iload_2       
     7: iflt          20               //
    10: iload_1       
    11: iload_2       
    12: iadd          
    13: istore_1      
    14: iinc          2, -1
    17: goto          6
    20: iload_1       
    21: ireturn       

public int loopM1Cond();
  Code:
     0: iconst_0      
     1: istore_1      
     2: sipush        1000
     5: istore_2      
     6: iload_2       
     7: iconst_m1                   //
     8: if_icmple     21            //
    11: iload_1       
    12: iload_2       
    13: iadd          
    14: istore_1      
    15: iinc          2, -1
    18: goto          6
    21: iload_1       
    22: ireturn
```

It is slightly more performant on my machine (to my surprise. I expected JIT to compile these loops into identical assembly.)

```
Benchmark                   Mode Thr     Mean   Mean error    Units
t.LoopCond.loopM1Cond       avgt   1    0,319        0,004  usec/op
t.LoopCond.loopZeroCond     avgt   1    0,302        0,004  usec/op
```

### Сonclusion

**Compare with zero** whenever sensible.